# QUERY no se ejecuta correctamente en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo dos consultas en `php`, después de usar `echo $id_inspirador` se imprime correctamente el valor del primer `query`, pero tengo un error respecto al segundo `Notice: Undefined index: id_proyecto`, no se si se pierde el valor de `$id_inspirador` al ejecutar el segundo query.

```
  $query = $con -> query ("SELECT id_inspirador FROM inspirador WHERE id_user = ".$id_user);
    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
      $id_inspirador = $fila['id_inspirador'];

  }

  $busqueda = $con -> query ("SELECT MAX(id_proyecto) FROM proyectos WHERE id_inspirador = ".$id_inspirador);
    while ($fila_busqueda = mysqli_fetch_assoc($busqueda)) {
      $id_proyecto = $fila_busqueda['id_proyecto'];       
  }
```

Comment: Hola tienes que colocare un alias   a la condición de vas para que que así le puedas obtener el valor en el array Ej:  MAX(id_proyecto) AS idproyecto y recuperes el valor así  $fila_busqueda['idproyecto'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema en la segunda query es que la columna que buscas no existe.  Te recomiendo que uses un alias asi:

```
$busqueda = $con -> query ("SELECT MAX(id_proyecto) AS max_id FROM proyectos WHERE id_inspirador = ".$id_inspirador);
while ($fila_busqueda = mysqli_fetch_assoc($busqueda)) {
  $id_proyecto = $fila_busqueda['max_id'];       
}
```